# How do I add a header to a single static file in IIS 10?

Tags: iis, http-headers, web.config

Server is Windows Server 2016

I need to serve a single static file with a different header than all the other files (`Cache-Control: max-age=15`)

A different answer gives the leaf XML node as: `<clientCache cacheControlCustom="private" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:15" />` but only how to apply it to every file.

File needs to be posted to our public web server quickly and updated quickly for debugging. Final application will not be using a static file.

Comment: IIS settings can be configured at file level via `<location>` tags. That's something you might explore and should fulfill your needs.

Comment: @LexLi: I ended up creating a new virtual directory in IIS to get the test URL up and running; however from a blog post that looks like a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stopgap answer:

Create a new virtual directory and put the file in it and set the header in `<customHeaders>` tag:

```
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="CacheControl" value="max-age=15" />
         </customHeaders>
```

There ought to be a better answer but this got me up and running.